# Ionic serve not working when i try to launch my project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

When I tried to use the ionic serve command in my ionic project, I get the following error.
I don't know why, can it be because i tried to launch my project on my external SSD???

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjIBs.png)

Comment: Have you installed the angular CLI globally?

Comment: Yes, I've done it

Comment: And so from that same command line where you try to launch ionic app what happens when you try `ng version`

Comment: I get: Angular CLI: 11.2.5

Comment: And have you run `npm i` in the project directory. Generally speaking, the more details you can give about your project and what you have already tried will help you getting a more detailed answer more quickly. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I guess the problem is you have not done `npm install` inside your project direct. Do it once and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove your node_modules folder
2. reinstall your modules with `npm i`
3. Verify that you have both, angular and ionic installed

If that did not succeed, you might just want to build a base project provided by the ionic team

```
ionic start
```

and then choose one of the provided starts:

```
> tabs         | A starting project with a simple tabbed interface
  sidemenu     | A starting project with a side menu with navigation in the content area
  blank        | A blank starter project
  list         | A starting project with a list
  my-first-app | An example application that builds a camera with gallery
  conference   | A kitchen-sink application that shows off all Ionic has to offer
```

This should work.